# Programatically change the color of a selector in normal state

Tags: android

I've got the below selector. It's in fact a shape inside a selector. I'm doing it like so because apparently Android 5 doesn't support a shape with corners unless it's inside a selector.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="@dimen/a_menu_corner_radius"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Anyway ... the thing is I want to change the color of the shape, programatically. I've created this util method:

```
/**
 * @param view
 * @param colorValue a color value, not a resource ID !!!
 * @throws java.lang.ClassCastException in case the drawable is not a selector
 */
public static void setColorToSelectorNormalState(View view, int colorValue) throws ClassCastException {
    if (view != null) {
        Drawable background = view.getBackground();
        if (!(background instanceof StateListDrawable)) {
            throw new ClassCastException("The drawable must inherit the StateListDrawable class. (the drawable set needs to be a selector !)");
        }

        ((StateListDrawable) background).addState(new int[]{android.R.attr./*?????????*/}, new ColorDrawable(colorValue));
    }
}
```

... but I can't figure out what to put as a state param. (see the /*????*/ part). The ting has only one state anyway, the "normal" one, but there's no state attribute for "normal", or is there?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is `StateSet.WILD_CARD`

```
 ((StateListDrawable) background).addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, new ColorDrawable(colorValue));
```

you can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/StateSet.html#WILD_CARD)

Comment: did you call also refreshDrawableState after you set the new state?

Comment: Nope, but I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work.